# Why aren't the CSS properties getting applied on jquery .click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get it so that when the first box is clicked, it's background color changes to red, but it's not working. I have tried a lot of different things, but none of them work! Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#one").click(function(){
                $("#one").addClass("open");
            });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .open{
            background-color: red;
        }
        html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }
        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }
        #title{
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
        }
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #left{
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0.5%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5%;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #right{
            width: 70%;
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0.5%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5%;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 30%;
            border-left: solid 2px black;
        }
        .card{
            height: 20%;
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: grey solid 2px;
        }
        .first{
            margin-top: 6.5%;
        }
        #one{
            background-color: green;
        }
        .second{
            margin-top: 50%;
        }
        #two{
            background-color: green;
        }
        #main{
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-top: 7.5%;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: grey solid 3px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
        <h1>Blah Blah Blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <div class="card first" id="oneBottom">
        </div>
        <div class="card first" id="one">
        </div>

        <div class="card second" id="twoBottom">
        </div>      
        <div class="card second" id="two">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OP subject might want to be altered.  The javascript is actually working.

Answer (score 4):

Your green color for #one is overriding it.  You can make .open { background-color: red !important; } to force it, but it may be better to put the green on a class that you remove from the element instead.  !important works, but I believe it is something to try to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The css for Id `#one` is prioritised,

Use,

```
#one.open {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Refer : **[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**